# C++ execute an action for each type in a given list

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, refactoring, variadic-templates

I have been given the charge to refactor old code and have stumbled upon this case:

```
void myClass::doStuff()
{
    for( myIterator< Type1 > it( this->getDatabase() ); it; ++it )
    {
        do1( *it );
        do2( *it );
        do3( *it );
    }
    for( myIterator< Type2 > it( this->getDatabase() ); it; ++it )
    {
        do1( *it );
        do2( *it );
        do3( *it );
    }
    for( myIterator< Type3 > it( this->getDatabase() ); it; ++it )
    {
        do1( *it );
        do2( *it );
        do3( *it );
    }
}
```

It's obviously bad since I copy basically the same code 3 times so I decided to refactor it using templates like this :

```
template<class _type> void myClass::do123()
{
    for( myIterator< _type > it( this->getDatabase() ); it; ++it )
    {
        do1( *it );
        do2( *it );
        do3( *it );
    }
}
void myClass::doStuffBetter()
{
    do123<Type1>();
    do123<Type2>();
    do123<Type3>();
}
```

Is there other easier/more productive ways to factorize this kind of repetition in code ?

Bonus question : if my types were not static but given in a variadic template how would I do a similar treatment ?

Comment: I don't see any problem with your `doStuffBetter` function. Looks readable and productive enough for me.

Comment: Given you have working code, this may be better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @lcs maybe but the second part of the question don't have any working code

Comment: @AlexandreTHOUVENIN: You shouldn't ask multiple questions in one question.

Comment: @Christian Hackl I though they were close enough but you are right

Comment: Do you have C++14, or are you really stuck in C++11?  Generic lambdas can make a similar solution inline.

Comment: @Yakk stuck in C++11, this has to work on game consoles and we have not yet tested C++14 properly on those devices (even if it should be supported), however I'm really interested in your answer since I know nothing about generic lambdas

Comment: With additional layer and variadic template, you may do `do123<Type1, Type2, Type3>();`. Not sure it is better here though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find your solution good enough.

Just for fun, I propose the following `doStuffBetter()`

```
template <typename ... Types>
void myClass::doStuffBetter()
 {
   int unused[] { (do123<Types>(), 0)... };

   (void)unused; // to avoid a warning
 }
```

Should work with C++11 and I suppose that can respond to your bonus question too.

Comment: It definitely answers the bonus question. I like how you used initializer_list to do the trick

Comment: @AlexandreTHOUVENIN - I'm not an expert and I'm not good in explaining but... the idea is initialize an array of `int`, so we create an environment where we can put a sequence of comma separated values, and every value for the array (a zero) is preceded by a value (`do123<Types>()`) that is discarded by the following comma

Answer (score 1):

You can use `boost::mpl::vector<>` as a list of types and `boost::mpl::for_each` to iterate over the types:

```
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/for_each.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

struct Type1 {};
struct Type2 {};
struct Type3 {};

template<class T>
struct Type
{
    typedef T agrument_type;
};

int main(int ac, char**) {
    using Types = boost::mpl::vector<Type1, Type2, Type3>;

    boost::mpl::for_each<Types, Type<boost::mpl::_1> >([](auto type_wrapper) {
        using Type = typename decltype(type_wrapper)::agrument_type;
        // Place your code here.
        std::cout << typeid(Type).name() << '\n';
    });
}
```

Outputs:

```
5Type1
5Type2
5Type3
```

---

If C++14 lambda with `auto` is unavailable, use the following functional object instead of the lambda function:

```
struct TypeCallback
{
    template<class TypeWrapper>
    void operator()(TypeWrapper) {
        using Type = typename TypeWrapper::agrument_type;
        // Place your code here.
        std::cout << typeid(Type).name() << '\n';
    }
};
```

And then:

```
boost::mpl::for_each<Types, Type<boost::mpl::_1> >(TypeCallback{});
```

---

Without boost, instead of using `boost::mpl::vector<>` and `boost::mpl::for_each`, just create a function that iterates over a hard-coded list of types:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template<class T>
struct Type
{
    typedef T agrument_type;
};

struct TypeCallback
{
    template<class TypeWrapper>
    void operator()(TypeWrapper) {
        using Type = typename TypeWrapper::agrument_type;
        // Place your code here.
        std::cout << typeid(Type).name() << '\n';
    }
};

struct Type1 {};
struct Type2 {};
struct Type3 {};

template<class F>
void for_each_mytype(F f) { // <--- one function per different list of types
    f(Type<Type1>{});
    f(Type<Type2>{});
    f(Type<Type3>{});
}

int main(int ac, char**) {
    for_each_mytype(TypeCallback{});
}
```

Comment: Boost does amazing things, I'm not using that in production code but definitely +1 for the originality

Comment: @AlexandreTHOUVENIN Added a version without Boost for you.

Comment: It brings something interesting, less elegant than type vector yet it still keeps the list of type somewhere else. It can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

This is a C++14 solution.

```
namespace notstd {
  template<class T> struct tag_t { constexpr tag_t() {}; using type=T; };
  template<class T> constexpr tag_t<T> tag{};
  template<class Tag> using type_t = typename Tag::type;

  template<class...Ts, class F>
  void for_each_type(F&& f) {
    using discard=int[];
    (void)discard{ 0,(void(
      f( tag<Ts> )
    ),0)...};
  }
}
```

that is some boilerplate.

Now we do:

```
void myClass::doStuffBetter()
{
  notstd::for_each_type<Type1,Type2,Type2>(
    [&](auto tag){
      using type=notstd::type_t<decltype(tag)>;
      for( myIterator<type> it( getDatabase() ); it; ++it )
      {
        do1( *it );
        do2( *it );
        do3( *it );
      }
    }
  );
}
```

we can go a step further and upgrade `myIterator<_type>` such that a default-constructed instance compares equal to the one-past-the-end iterator.

```
namespace notstd {
  template<class It>
  struct range_t {
    It b, e;
    It begin() const { return b; }
    It end() const { return e; }
  };

  template<class It>
  range_t<It> range( It s, It f = {} ) {
    return {std::move(s), std::move(f)};
  }
}
```

then we get:

```
void myClass::doStuffBetter()
{
  notstd::for_each_type<Type1,Type2,Type2>(
    [&](auto tag){
      using type=notstd::type_t<decltype(tag)>;
      for( auto&& e : notstd::range( myIterator<type>( getDatabase() ) )
      {
        do1( e );
        do2( e );
        do3( e );
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: I really like your for_each_type, even if it's C++14 I might use this kind of solutions in other projects or even later in the same project, +1 obviously. The iterator upgrade is also good, if the codebase using it wasn't that huge, I'd probably go for that